# How do I write a full path in a controller in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to write the full path so need to know what the rails_root domain is.  How do I do that?  For example:

```
string = "{RAILS_ROOT}/vendors/#{@vendor.id}"
```

What is the equivalent of "RAILS_ROOT" to give me what the full domain is for my application?  So that in development it would subsstitute localhost:3000 and on my heroku site the right full domain?

Comment: I added more info to the answer.

Comment: BTW, in Rails 3 you should use Rails.root instead of RAILS_ROOT. RAILS_ROOT is deprecated.

Comment: Rails.root I guess isn't right it just gives the file path, no tdomain....how do I do it....

Answer (score 2):

You should always avoid, if possible, hard-coding your path, because it is less flexible and more prone to result in broken links in the future. Plus, you can use Rails routing, which is an elegant way to generate everything cohesively in Rails without any need to create the composite parts yourself.

If you have your routes set up properly, you should be able to call:

```
link_to "View vendor", vendor_url(@vendor.id)
```

`Vendor_url(@vendor.id)` in Rails gives you your full URL, which you can then contain in your `string` variable. Here's how to generate the routes needed for the above:

```
# in routes.rb
resources :vendors
```

Comment: Try `vendor_url(@vendor.id).to_s`.

Comment: do the path helpers work -- I read that they don't in a controlller...?

Comment: The helpers *should* work in a controller if you have the resources defined in the `config/routes.rb` file.

Comment: hmm...they are defined....helpers typically don't work in controllers thus the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
File.realpath(RAILS_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could access the request object. **request.host_with_port** would give you the hostname and port. **request.protocol** will give you the protocol (http:// or https://). **request.fullpath** will give you the path with query params.